# Systems of First Order Linear Equations- graph of real valued solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following system.

\begin{pmatrix}\frac{-1}{2}& 1\\-1& \frac{-1}{2}\end{pmatrix}

Find a fundamental set of ‘real–valued’ solutions of the system. Which i found out to be:

u(t) = $e^{\frac{-t}{2}} \begin{pmatrix}cost\\-sin t\end{pmatrix}$ , v(t)= $e^{\frac{-t}{2}} \begin{pmatrix}sint\\cost\end{pmatrix}$.

b). Use MATHEMATICA’s VectorPlot command to plot the direction field.

(c) Use MATHEMATICA’s StreamPlot command to plot phase portrait for the system.

(d) Based on the plots in (b) and (c), comment on the nature of the solutions and any
possible critical point.

I have difficulty in plotting this on Mathematica 5.2 as I am novice to this software and little help from someone would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You need [Mathematica.SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Kaster: Thanks, but i just help with commands to be used only. VectorPlot in mathematica 5.2 gives no graphical output.

Comment: @Avinesh: I added another phase portrait and direction field plot using a different tool, so you can contrast them. Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, here is a plot using a different tool.

[image]

Using Mathematica v9.0, a vector plot is done using:

```
VectorPlot[{(-1/2) x + y, -x - (1/2) y}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

The output is:

[image]

A stream plot is done using:

```
StreamPlot[{(-1/2) x + y, -x - (1/2) y}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

A color stream plot is done using:

```
StreamDensityPlot[{(-1/2) x + y, -x - (1/2) y}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, StreamStyle -> Black, VectorPoints -> Automatic, VectorStyle -> White, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

That plot (you have many options) is:

[image]

We can also plot $u(t), v(t)$ as functions of time and this is:

[image]

An analysis shows:

- We have a critical point at $(x, y) = (0, 0)$.
- The eigenvalues are complex conjugate with negative real part, so we have a spiral into the origin, that is a stable system.

Comment: Thanks Amzoti.Just wanted to know if we could fancy the plots using rainbow colours or other features to enhance the look of the plot.

Comment: By the way which version of mathematica did you use because the above command fails in Mathematica 5.2.

Comment: If you move the last plot up and down while looking at it, it looks like a horrible whirlpool on the page. :)

Comment: @Amzoti: That would be wonderful.

Comment: What would the plots of V(t) look? Is it the last graph?

Comment: Thanks Amzoti, for the additional plots.

Comment: u[t] = Exp[-t/2] (Cos[t] + Sin[t]), v[t] = Exp[-t/2] (-Sin[t] + Cos[t]),
 Plot[{u[t], v[t]}, {t, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}] Mathematica 5.2 fails

Comment: Gives out the same text i typed. So i believe it does not work in mathematica 5.2

Comment: Wow! What more can I say? +1